# How do i can modify List Property in ASP.NET Razor Pages?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I am trying to delete a row from the table. I get the data when the page is loaded and it must be possible to delete one or more of these data. I managed to delete the row from the UI with javascript, however when I submit the form the propty doesn't get it with what data is left

So I don't know how to tell the backend what data I deleted.
I tried to do everything in Javascript, but i can't Modify the modelstate there.
thank you for your help

```
   @for (int i=0;i < Model.AuftragsNummern.Count ;i++){
                          @Html.Hidden("Model.AuftragsNummern.index", i)
                          @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AuftragsNummern[i])
                            <input type="hidden" name="Model.AuftragsNummern.index" value="@Model.AuftragsNummern" />
                            <tr>
                              <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.AuftragsNummern[i])</td>
                              <td><button asp-page-handler="AuftragDelete" onclick="deleteAuftrage(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">delete</button></td>
                              @{}
                          </tr>

[BindProperty]
public List<int> AuftragsNummern { get; set; }


    function deleteAuftrage(btn){
      var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode
      row.parentNode.removeChild(row)  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Model Binding binds the property by name attribute which is in the frontend.

Only input/select/textarea type element with value can be bind to the backend when form submit, but your js just delete the row of `@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.AuftragsNummern[i])`, multiple input elements still exists.

Here is a whole working demo you could follow:

Page

```
@page
@model IndexModel
<form method="post">
    <table>
        @for (int i = 0; i < Model.AuftragsNummern.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => Model.AuftragsNummern[i])</td>
                <td><button onclick="deleteAuftrage(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">delete</button></td>
                <input type="hidden" name="AuftragsNummern" value="@Model.AuftragsNummern[i]" />

            </tr>
        }
    </table>
    
   <input type="submit" value="POST" />
</form>
   
@section Scripts
{
    <script>
    function deleteAuftrage(btn) {
        var row = btn.parentNode.parentNode
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row)
    }
    </script>
}
```

PageModel

```
   public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    [BindProperty]
    public List<int> AuftragsNummern { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        AuftragsNummern = new List<int>() { 1, 5, 6, 9, 7 };
    }
    public  void OnPost()
    {


    }
}
```

Result
[image]

Comment: nice, thanks a lot for your effort!!
I actually found a similar solution yesterday, that has the same approach



   @Html.Hidden("AuftragsNummern", Model.AuftragsNummern[i])